# How does return affect the process of creating an object without parentheses

Tags: javascript, class, syntax

```
function B(){}

function A(){
    return B;
}

function C(){
    return "text";
}

new A;         //function B(){}
new C;         //C {}
```

Notice there is no `()` after `new A` and `new C`. Normally we would do something like `new A()` and I thought this would cause an error but it just runs fine. Now I have never used `new` like this before and this seems weird to me. For some reason they worked but `new A` is returning the function `B` meanwhile `new C` is returning the newly created object with the constructor as `C`.

Also I don't know why `A` and `C` are "automatically" executed, and an explanation would be great. Thanks.

Comment: look at String(new C). to see the text of the output object. it's a lot like a new Sting("text"), but with your constructor instead of String as the constructor. I've only seen Strings do this, but it probably happens to Numbers as well.

Comment: the same effect is true when using bind(). i wanted a way to reverse the arguments on a function to allow me to pre-bind everything but the data, which usually comes first, by saying cb=f.bind(true,"Titles",6); to detect that, if(this==true) is obvously worthless, and this===true is false, so i had to say if(String(this)==="true") to detect the bound this boolean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new A` vs. `new A()` thing is just a quirk of the grammar, they're exactly equivalent. If you leave off the parentheses, it's exactly as though you had included them. The new object is created, given the prototype `A.prototype`, and then `A` is called with the new object as `this`. The parentheses are only required if you have arguments to pass to the constructor function.

> How does return affect the process of creating an object without parentheses

The return value of the constructor function is not affected in any way by whether you use `()` in the `new` expression. Again, `new A` and `new A()` are exactly equivalent.

Here's the deal on the return value of a constructor function (whether or not `()` are used): The `new` operator creates an object, and the result of a `new` expression is a reference to that object **unless** the constructor function returns a non-`null` object reference. If it returns any primitive (such as `"text"`), or `null`, its return value is *completely ignored* by the `new` operator and the result of the `new` expression is the object `new` created. The only time `new` returns anything other than the object it created is if the constructor function returns a non-`null` object reference; in that case, the result of the `new` expression is the object reference returned by the constructor function. This exception makes it possible to return an existing object to satisfy the `new` semantics rather than a new object.

All the gory details are in the spec, [§11.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) and [§13.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) (in turgid prose).

Comment: Is the syntax `new A` described in the specification?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Yes, in [§11.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) and [§11.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2) (I believe); this business of the parentheses being optional if you have no arguments for the constructor function is a reasonably well-known grammar quirk. I'm not saying it's easy to read (and if you think ES5 is difficult, you should see the ES6 spec -- I sometimes wonder if they actively want people not to be able to read it).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: It comes down to this: `new` **always** runs the function you give it, so the parens are optional (unlike a function call, where you need the parens to tell the engine whether you're referring to the function object or *calling* the function).

Comment: I can understand the spec after rereading a few times. Anyway, thanks! Now I know I can safely omit the parentheses when creating objects to save me some typing works.

Comment: jslint barks about missing parens on constructors because it makes code more readable to press the extra 3 keys...

Comment: [SHIFT]+[9]+[0] = 3 keys ;)